# Открыть два профиля google chrome по определенным координатам

Tags: google-chrome

Нужно открыть два профиля google chrome по определенным координатам, один над другим. Прописал в свойства ярлыков:

```
 --profile-directory="Profile 1" --window-position=110,0 --window-size=1050,500
 --profile-directory="Profile 2" --window-position=110,500 --window-size=1050,500
```

По отдельности всё работает, но если запустить два вместе, то второй открывается по координатам первого. Как можно исправить?